# Symbolizing layer with graduated colors by a field in Excel File

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, excel

I have a field in Excel file called percentage, I want the governorates colored by the percentage value, so the more value is the more red become darker in the governorate.

So how can I do it in ArcMap?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our Focused question/Best answer model operates. We are not a tutorial site. Questions are expected to show effort toward solving the task, along with a detailed description of the environment, data, and problem encountered, including any error messages. Please [Edit] the Question to describe what you have attempted and what has gone wrong.

Comment: Read the help file and check out the section on symbolising the layer using unique categories.